Queuing in Quantum Circuits
In classical computing, buffers, queues and schedulers are fairly commonplace. In quantum computing too there are methods to do batch and sequential processing on circuits. However, as per my knowledge,these schemes wait for the entire circuit output and then "send in" the next input.
So I was wondering: Is it physically viable to have a buffer in between layers (or gates) of a quantum circuit of large depth and have sequential computation where we do not wait for a previous computation to go to completion?
In my opinion, this may be a more optimal scheme especially when the same large depth circuit has to be run multiple times. Could you please point me to relevant resources in relation to this?
(Sorry for the slightly vague question, it is my first on this forum)

This is a great question. But personally, I think the term "Buffer" is quite intriguing. In my opinion, Parallelism and Quantum Memory research advancement (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.14432) may be a good resource to handle what you describe as "Buffer". In addition, there is Quantum intermediate measurement and conditional gate, which can also be used to handle "buffering probably". Resources on Quantum Error Correction Schemes used in measurement-based quantum computing (MBQC) can be check as it uses intermediate results as a step in sequential processing
